# Nxt Touch Sensor different

Tags: java, sensors, eclipse-oxygen, nxt

I am asking in this website to ask if someone knew how to translate the LEGO MINDSTORMS Touch Sensor function of Pressed, Bumped, and Released to eclipse-oxygen language. I already know pressed:

```
TouchSensor touch = new TouchSensor(SensorPort.S1);
  int count = 0 ;
  while(count<10){ 
      if(touch.isPressed()){
```

}

So I ask to know if someone knew the code for it to act when it is BUMPED. Please and thanks for your help.

Comment: Hard to answer as there are a lot of things that can happen when it is bumped. What do you want to happen?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is a development environment and supports many different programming languages, so 'eclipse-oxygen language' doesn't mean anything.

Comment: My bad, it is Java language, greg-449

Comment: The NXT has a hammer in motor 3. The other 2 motors are used for the wheels. I have 2 touch sensors connected. If the left touch sensor is pressed, then the left wheel will run. Right Sensor, Right wheel. If both are pressed, then it will go straight forward. So I want the Motor3 (hammer) to run when The left and the right sensor are bumped together. @burrito77

Comment: So I'm guessing SensorPort.S1 is equal to either the right or left touch sensor, right? I'll post my idea after your response, but just be aware that it'll mostly be psuedocode, as I don't know all of your methods, classes, and such for this, but it seems like you're using multiple classes right?

Comment: yes, it indeed is. I appreciate any type of possible help as I cant find any information related to it in the Internet. I use Payment class. @burrito77